# What is the C++CLI equivalent of vb's Nothing?

Tags: c++-cli

I'm in this kind of a place

```
generic <typename ItemType> where ItemType : ItemBase
public ref class Container {
    ItemType GetItem(int i) {
        ...
        if (someSpecialCondition) return ???
        ...
    }
};
```

I want to return the equivalent of vb's "Nothing" but can't figure out the syntax for it. It doesn't like null or nullptr, I know that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty unintuitive for generics, note that it can't be `nullptr` if the type parameter is a value class.  It also does not match the language spec, which promises that nullptr is valid when the type is constrained to `ref class`.

The default value for type `T` is `T()`.  So it is:

```
ItemType GetItem(int i) {
    ...
    if (someSpecialCondition) return ItemType();
    ...
}
```

Which produces nullptr if ItemType is a reference type and the default value (all members zero-initialized) when ItemType is a value type.  Same thing that `Nothing` does in VB.NET